# When is the virtual function table set to 0

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm analyzing an access violation in our application that occurs because it tries to call a virtual function on an object whose virtual function table points to 0. So I'd like to know at what points in an object's lifetime is the virtual function table pointer not set or explicitly set to zero?

(We use Visual C++ 10 as a compiler.)

Comment: It may be easier to solve your problem if you were able to replicate your problem in code. Perhaps you have an instance of UB due to misusing an object under construction.

Comment: This feels like the wrong approach. Run your program though a memory debugger first and figure out if you aren't double-deleting something, or something along those lines.

Comment: I would if I could but unfortunately the problem doesn't arise on our development systems, so I only have dump files to analyze.

Comment: This is a typical outcome of heap corruption.  The v-table pointer is fairly vulnerable since it is the first field in the object so a small buffer overwrite is enough to whack it.

Comment: A memory corruption is certainly also on my list of possible causes but it didn't look like a typical memory corruption to me so I wanted to investigate other possibilities, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vtable pointer will never be 0 while the object is in a valid state.  During construction and destruction, while the object has a dynamic type of an abstract base class, the vtable will point to the abstract base class vtable, which will include pure virtual functions, but the vtable pointer itself will still be non-zero.

The only time the vtable pointer can be zero is before construction or after destruction.

Comment: So will the last destructor of my class explicitly set the vtable pointer to zero? Then I would assume that I'm dealing with an object that should have been deleted but still remains more or less intact until it is overwritten in memory?

Comment: It doesn't need to (once the object is fully destructed there are no requirements on its state) but doing so can help catch errors. The alternative is memory corruption.

Comment: This was it: the object was already destroyed but from another thread, so the access violation was subject to a racing condition.

Answer (score 1):

If the vtable pointer is truly zero, then you may have used a VC++ extension such as:

```
class __declspec(novtable) Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual void proc();
};
```

Here `__declspec(novtable)` tells the compiler the class doesn't need a vtable, because no virtual functions will be called on it until a derived class has installed its own vtable. If you then call Base::proc() before that has happened, you may get the error.

More likely the vtable itself is non-zero, but function's slot in it is zero, due to the function being pure virtual:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void proc() = 0;
};
```

and then someone called it anyway with code like:

```
void Derived::proc() {
    Base::proc();
    // Derived-specific stuff here.
};
```

This can happen because the author of Derived assumed their override needed to call the Base version, even though the Base version doesn't exist.

Either way, one approach to finding this would be to stop all the base class shenanigans, define the function normally, and see what calls it. Eg:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void proc() {
        assert( typeof(*this) != typeof(Base) ); // Break-point here.
    }
};
```

Comment: Neither of this. The debugger explicitly shows the vtable pointer to be zero and hence cannot even show the individual entries.